# Mark Row as important and keep it saved each time it loads

Tags: php, javascript

[image: Table a]

This is TableA, when i click on Button "click here", every time particular table gets loaded using this code

```
<tr>
    <th style="height: 25px">NAME</th>
    <th style="height: 25px">EMAIL</th>
    <th style="height: 25px">CELL NO</th>
    <th style="height: 25px">CITY</th>
    <th style="height: 25px; width:120px">DATE APPLIED</th>
    <th style="height: 25px">POST A MESSAGE TO CANDIDATE</th>
    <th style="height: 25px">DETAILED CV</th>
    <th>Hide Candidate</th>
    <th>MARK AS IMPORTANT</th>
</tr>                                              
<!-- /headings -->
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    echo "<script>window.location = \"#showcand\";</script>";                                            
    if($result) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan=\"4\" ><p align=\"center\" class=\"message\"><blink><span style=\"color:red;\" > NO CANDIDATE APPLIED</span></blink></p></td>";    
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        while($data_set1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                                            
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set1['ename']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set1['eemail']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecell']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set1['ecity']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$data_set1['date_of_jobapply']}</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"reply.php?tid={$_SESSION['vid']}&id=1&name={$data_set1['ename']}&email={$data_set1['eemail']} \"><input class=\"button\" name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"POST\" /></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"detailcv.php?id={$data_set1['eid']}\" target=\"_blank\"><input  style=\" cursor:hand;width:40px\" class=\"button\" name=\"cv\" type=\"button\" value=\"C V\" /></a></td>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"hide_cand\" id=\"hide_cand\"onclick=\"return hideRow(this)\"/></td>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"imp_cand\" id=\"hide_cand\"/></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } ?>
```

in last column i want to mark particular row as imp and not imp using check box, and everytime i load this table i should see imp marked row as it is, how it can be done..

Comment: Have you tried something? Take a look at AJAX. Or you can use form which you will submit when checkbox clicked. Than just write checked/not checked into database.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make a field for that in the database and fire an ajax query each time anyone marks it as important to change the field of that value to 1 from 0.  1 being Important and 0 being not important or anything of that sort.

And when u run the query to fetch the result fetch the flag also and set the checkbox accordingly.

You can echo `checked="checked"` where the value for (lets say `isimportant`) gets 1.

Comment: `echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"markimp\" id=\"mark_imp\"onclick=\"return markimp(this)\" checked=\"checked\"/></td>";` i have upadated this line and added 0 as default value in database ,and fetched that value ,and added this function onclick `function markimp(checkbox)
{
    if(confirm(' are you sure you want to Select this Candidate? '))
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE applyjob SET marked_impval='1' WHERE jobid='".$id."' AND eid='".employee.eid."' AND marked_impval='0'") or die(mysql_error());
 
    }
    return false;
}`but it is not giving proper result